# Can Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA use the same workspace without conflict?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I'm using both IDEs for some projects and I was thinking of using the same "workspace" folder with both IDEs. Is there any known problems for doing this? Conflicts between IDEs or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each IntelliJ project saves its setting within the project folder. With Eclipse, there is **one** common folder in "workspace" folder contains infomation about list of projects in this workspace.
It's safe to save using same "workspace" folder.

But the terminologies in 2 IDE are different, in Eclipse there are **workspaces**, under each **workspace**, there are multiple **projects**. But in IntelliJ there are **projects** and each **project** has multiple **modules**.

If your projects stand alone, IntelliJ project = Eclipse project. But if you have some projects relate to each other, **IntelliJ project = Eclipse workspace**, **IntelliJ module = Eclipse project**

Comment: *All eclipse projects save their settings in one common folder in "workspace" folder.* - And what are `.settings`, `.classpath` and `.project` **in the project** folder?

Comment: @AleksandrM thanks, long time no use Eclipse so I forget that. I have updated my answer